# Can a graphical front end be added to server like X11?

Tags: server

I just installed Ubuntu server 16.04.3 and found out that it is command line based. Can a graphical front end be added so it is easier to use like X11? Not much in command lines since Dos 6.0. Thanks for the help, we are new to linux...

Answer (score 0):

You can install the package `ubuntu-desktop` (that is the basic desktop environment delivered with the main ubuntu flavor) via command-line then you have a fully fledged desktop system.

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

The same can be accomplished by using `tasksel`

```
sudo tasksel
```

There you can chose packages with <kbd>Space</kbd> and when youre done selecting you can hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to highlight 'O.K.' and hit <kbd>Return</kbd>. Make sure you only select one desktop environment.

Alternatively you can download the desktop images [here](https://www.ubuntu.com/desktop) and reinstall fresh if you not have much done to the system yet.